# How do I Set Variable Dependent on Another Variable to Update when the Original Variable Updates?

Tags: python, variables

In python, let's run the following lines of code:

```py
x = 0
y = x
x += 1
print(y)
print(x)
```

The first line of output is clearly different from the second, even though we set `x=y` in line 2. Anyone experienced with programming as a whole would know that.

However, is there a way to make `x` update as `y` does?

Comment: You cannot make two variables inherently linked to each other, but you can make two variables refer to the same object and then mutate that object, and the changes will be reflected in both variables, obviously, since they are referring to the same object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @juanpa's comment, you can get this behavior if you wrap the value in a list:

```
x = [0]
y = x
x[0] += 1
print(y[0])
print(x[0])
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped. However, _why_ don't raw variables work like this in Python? For example, in PHP, you could specify if the variables should reflect changes. Could you point me to some documentation with further information about this? Thank you.

Comment: I imagine they don't work that way in Python because, in most situations (heck, nearly all situations), that's not how you you would _want_ them to work.  This link might be helpful https://realpython.com/pointers-in-python/

Comment: Thank you for that link. This link clearly explains that some types are immutable and some are mutable (which should clearly be obvious, but I didn't notice).

Answer (score 1):

I am using the [observer design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*-coding: utf-8 -*-


class X:
    def __init__(self, subject):
        self.subject = subject
        self.subject.register(self)
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.data = self.subject.data


class Y:
    def __init__(self, data=10):
        self.data = data
        self._observers = list()

    def set(self, value):
        self.data = value
        self.notify()

    def register(self, observer):
        self._observers.append(observer)

    def notify(self):
        for ob in self._observers:
            ob.update()


y = Y(1)
x = X(y)
assert x.data == 1 and y.data == 1

y.set(20)
assert x.data == 20 and y.data == 20

y.set(-1)
assert x.data == -1 and y.data == -1
```

Comment: Hello @Shuo, I don't understand your response. Does this mean you are using classes to do it? Or are you using `assert` commands? I am not very experienced at python, so I do not know what you are trying to express.

Comment: Yes, I use classes. The assert commands are just for verifying the values of x and y. I think @JohnGordon has a better example for you. I don't think whether a type is immutable is the problem here. Like @juanpa's comment, you should set both variables to the same object and modify the data owned by that object. In @John's answer, both variables point to the same object which is a `list` then you change the value owned by this list. If you are familiar with C, the x and y in this case is similar to the pointers that contains the address of a memory location and this location stores the value

Comment: You could use the command `id` to check if two variables are the same object. `x = [0]; y = x` then you will find actually `id(x) == id(y)` so if you change one of them, the other will change as well because they are basically the same thing. If you use `x = 1` then next time you assign a new value to it such as `x = 2` then the `id(x)` actually changes. I am not able to comment under other answers because I have low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 1
y = lambda: x
x += 2
print(x, y())
```

Not exatcly what you asked, but I thought it worth mentioning, depending on your use case this could solve your problem.